# Can I simulate slow loading of image in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Already referenced the answer below

[Simulate slow loading of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513421/simulate-slow-loading-of-image)

slowing down internet connection with chrome developer works but loading the entire site is slow, would like to focus on just the image reloading.

one of the answers suggested **deelay.me** which seems to be down already

Thank you for any input

Comment: add a wrapper around img tag and use setTImeout to add src attribute?

Comment: Filter requests for images through an endpoint which does the following: send the correct MIME header (e.g. `image/jpeg`), then open the image file and send it in chunks, with a delay of your choosing between chunks. That will cause images to trickle back from the server to the client, rather than loading as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout()` on the HTTP request. This will delay the loading of the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can lazy load your image and show the loading gif on the image placeholder when the IMG tag is fetching the image.

[How to show a "loading" gif image on top of a image placeholder during lazyload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530520/how-to-show-a-loading-gif-image-on-top-of-a-image-placeholder-during-lazyload)